# Python list-like object buffered to file?

Tags: python, list

Before I reinvent the wheel, does there exist in Python a module that provides a simplistic class similar to a list that buffers itself to a file as needed?

In particular, I would like to do something like this:

```
b = BufferedList(limit = 10000, tmp = '/tmp')
b.append(some_tuple)
b.append(some_tuple)
b.append(some_tuple)
# ad nauseam
```

This would create a buffered list named b. If the memory consumption of b exceeded 10000K bytes, further appends would write to a temp file.

Simple iteration is all I really need from the class. Features like pop, del, sort, and so forth would be nice but are not mandatory. The list will primarily contain tuples of strings.

I am using 2.7.

This will be implemented on Windows Server 2003.

**Edit:** As pointed out obliquely by Davidmh in the comments, I was really going at this backwards *for my needs*.

Since I do not really need pop, del, sort and other list manipulation methods, the cleanest solution for my needs today is just to set an appropriately large value for buffer when calling open() and always write to file if I think that it might possibly be needed.

I will just add a flag to my SQL tasks. It will probably end up with something like this:

```
imp = SqlImportTask()
imp.src_cs = std_config.DB04_CS
imp.dst_cs = std_config.SQL07_CS
imp.sql = 'SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrderDetail'
imp.dst_table = 'dbo.PurchaseOrderDetail'
imp.use_tmp_file = True
```

Comment: What do you expect to gain from this? If your process is consuming too much memory let the OS handle the pagination.

Comment: Memory consumption is a bit hard to define in Python, and also quite hard to implement. Do you only mean the size of the object references in the list? Its internal capacity? The size of all objects referenced by the list (recursively or not? or a hybrid?)? What about the things? What if an object is references multiple times? What should the list do if an object's "size" changes under your feet? How can it even notice that?

Comment: RedX, I will be reading tuples of strings of unknown size from an ODBC connection and then writing them out to another ODBC connection. The data might only be 10KB, but could easily be 1GB. The read has to be done as quickly as possible, so I cannot read/write, read/write. This will be on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: @Xevious Could you pipeline it somehow instead of reading the whole list at once?  Create an object that handles fetching X rows at a time and yield the data.  Read from that generator and insert to your other connection, possibly also in batches so you can use Batch SQL.

Comment: delnan, I have edited the question to reflect that I would be storing mostly tuples of strings. Monitoring the memory is something that I have concerns about also. One (possibly naive) approach would be to keep a running total of memory used and update it with each append, pop, del, etc. This would not take into account objects possibly changing on the fly. In my application, objects in the list would never be modified - however, the possibility does create some challenges for a more comprehensive implementation.

Comment: @Xevious When I need a temporary storage area, sometimes I use sqlite.  It's pretty simple to use, really, but the best solution I think would involve not keeping data in memory or on disk longer than you have to.

Comment: woot, the ODBC read will read data from an ancient legacy system that is not true client/server. It uses a linked database and very little locking. So, the read has to take place as quickly as possible and all in one go. The more delay, the more chance that the data has changed.

Comment: If I don't create this buffered tuple list myself, I might just create two reader classes - one that always uses a temp file and one that never uses a temp file. That isn't quite as elegant as I like, but it would certainly be less complex.

Comment: I asked a similar question regarding arrays in another venue. The take home was that there is no such a thing, and you can just write everything to a file and let the OS cache keep it in memory for you if it is small enough. Help it using a big buffer. Reading from your data stream should not be a problem, you read it, keep it in memory, flush it to disk when appropiate.

Comment: Davidmh - Thank you! I had forgotten all about being able to set the buffer size of the file object when calling open(). While not as exotic as some file backed list-like object, it does solve my immediate problem neatly.

Answer (score -1):

In Python there is a library for object serialization named [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Pickle car save an object into a file, but cannot manage the memory automatically.

Comment: I have used pickle often. In this case, serialization is not the issue - instead, I am looking for some paging functionality.